# define local costmap size

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, local-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, all,

How do I limit the size of my local cost map?

I am using move_base as my navigational stack.
each time the stack starts, the entire map was loaded as local cost map.

how do I confine it to the viewable range?

regards
Ray

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186321/define-local-costmap-size/) by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2014-07-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to modify whats in your local_costmap_params.yaml. First you have to make sure that you are not using a static map, "static_map:false", and then you just add the size of the costmap with "width: X" "height: Y", furthermore you should make sure that you use a rolling window map with the local costmap "rolling_window: true". For further imformation you can check this wiki http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d .

---

Originally posted by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) with karma: 363 on 2014-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on 2014-07-16**:
yep. brilliant!